# Iterate over enum?

Tags: c#, syntax, enums

I'm trying to iterate over an enum, and call a method using each of its values as a parameter. There has to be a better way to do it than what I have now:

```
foreach (string gameObjectType in Enum.GetNames(typeof(GameObjectType)))
{
     GameObjectType kind = (GameObjectType) Enum.Parse(typeof (GameObjectType), gameObjectType);
     IDictionary<string, string> gameObjectData = PersistentUtils.LoadGameObject(kind, persistentState);
}

//...

public static IDictionary<string, string> LoadGameObject(GameObjectType gameObjectType, IPersistentState persistentState) { /* ... */ }
```

Getting the enum names as strings, then parsing them back to enums, feels hideous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Iterating through an enum? (Indexing a System.Array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482729/c-sharp-iterating-through-an-enum-indexing-a-system-array)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, you can use [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx):

```
foreach (GameObjectType type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(GameObjectType))
{
    ...
}
```

It's not strongly typed though - and IIRC it's pretty slow. An alternative is to use my [UnconstrainedMelody project](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/):

```
// Note that type will be inferred as GameObjectType :)
foreach (var type in Enums.GetValues<GameObjectType>())
{
    ...
}
```

UnconstrainedMelody is nice if you're doing a lot of work with enums, but it might be overkill for a single usage...

Comment: You can also not be lazy and use GameObjectType in the second example instead of var :)

Comment: @Charles: I was doing that to demonstrate that it really was strongly typed... in the first version that would end up with it being `object`.

Comment: All right, I suppose I'll let it go this time. Just way too many C# examples nowadays that lazily use var for everything.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung why is it laziness? Removing visual clutter from the code is a Good Thing. This avoids nonsense like `MyLongAndDescriptiveClassName myLongAndDescriptiveClassNameInstance = new MyLongAndDescriptiveClassName(... )`. 
(maybe an argument for another place)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else <strike>is crazy enough to want to do</strike> wants to do this in C++/CLI, here's a port which works:

```
using namespace System;

enum class GameObjectType
{
    num1 = 1,
    num2 = 2,
};

Array^ objectTypes = Enum::GetValues(GameObjectType::typeid);
for each( GameObjectType^ objectType in objectTypes)
{
    // Do something
}
```