# Is there a better way to enumerate an enum's values than Enum.GetValues()?

Tags: c#

There are several situations where I want to have an `IEnumerable<MyEnum>` of enum values. The code I normally use looks like this:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).OfType<MyEnum>()
```

But not only is it not very pretty to look at, most people will need a couple of seconds to understand what it does. It's also a huge pain to write, especially when you need it on multiple occasions throughout the code.

To make my life easier, I've decided to write an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>(this T e) where T : Enum
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).OfType<T>();
}
```

Except I have to get rid of the `where T : Enum` part, because "*Constraint cannot be special class 'Enum'*". Also, it's not exactly what I want, because instead of `MyEnum.GetValues()` I'd need to write `MyEnum.Value.GetValues()`, which is quite confusing and not very pretty either.

Which leads me to this question: Is there a better way to get an `IEnumerable<MyEnum>` of enum values than using `Enum.GetValues()`?

Do I really have no other choice but to make it `Helper.GetEnumValues<MyEnum>()`?

If possible, I'd like a solution that works in Unity, but any solution would be appreciated either way.

Comment: "most people will need a couple of seconds to understand what it does" why do you say that?  It's perfectly understandable to me.  I'm not trying to be cocky; my point is: there is a wide range of experience among developers.  You shouldn't worry about what other developers might think, as long as you're writing reasonably-short statements.  It's their burden to understand it.  If you really think it's not clear, you could always adorn it with a comment.

Comment: If you rename `Helper` to `Enums` and `GetEnumValues` to `For`, it becomes shorter and self-documenting: `var firstEnum = Enums.For<MyEnum>().first();

Comment: Eleven different answers in the marked duplicate, and most if not all essentially being to call `GetValues()`, suggests that's as good as it gets. I would use `Cast<T>()` instead of `OfType<T>()` -- the former is more like a regular cast, while the latter is more like using the `as` operator -- but there aren't built-in options better than this. See, however, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2632759 for a solution that actually _does_ constrain the method call to enum types.

Comment: I'll point out that at the very least, you don't need to use extension method syntax if you don't want. If it's "not pretty", then just write `EnumExtensionClass.GetValues<T>(T e)` (shorten `EnumExtensionClass` to whatever you like, of course).

Comment: If you do like the extension method syntax, you don't need to care what you extend. This is equivalent: `public static IEnumerable<T> EnumValues<T>(this object unused) where T : struct { return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).OfType<T>(); }` Now you can call `this.EnumValues<MyEnum>()` almost anywhere: `this` is unused :)

Comment: You can use `Enum<MyEnum>.GetValues()` if you define the following static class in your namespace: `public static class Enum<T> { 
public static IEnumerable<T> GetValues() => Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>(); }` _(You can also use the opportunity to create cache-backed versions of this frequently used `Enum` methods if you're finding them to be a bottleneck.)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the perfect solution. .Net does not offer a strongly-typed Enum.GetValues at this time. People will only take a few seconds to understand what this does because one would expect .Net to offer a strongly-typed enumeration of Enums of one type right now.

You're using GetValues correctly as [MSDN suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx).