# Can you loop through an enum in C#?

Tags: c#, enums

```
for (int i = (int)MY_ENUM.First; i <= (int)MY_ENUM.Last; i++)
{
    //do work
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Your code will only work for enums that are backed by ints, where the range is consecutive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Iterating through an enum? (Indexing a System.Array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482729/c-sharp-iterating-through-an-enum-indexing-a-system-array)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should be able to utilize the following:

```
foreach (MY_ENUM enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MY_ENUM)))
{
   // Do work.
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx):

```
foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MY_ENUM))) { ... }
```

Answer (score 8):

Enums are kind of like integers, but you can't rely on their values to always be sequential or ascending. You can assign integer values to enum values that would break your simple `for` loop:

```
public class Program
{
    enum MyEnum
    {
        First = 10,
        Middle,
        Last = 1
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = (int)MyEnum.First; i <= (int)MyEnum.Last; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i); // will never happen
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As others have said, [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) is the way to go instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `public static Array GetValues(Type enumType)` method returns an array with the values of the anEnum enumeration. Since arrays implements  the IEnumerable interface, it is possible to enumerate them.
For example :

```
 EnumName[] values = (EnumName[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumName));
 foreach (EnumName n in values) 
     Console.WriteLine(n);
```

You can see more detailed explaination at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx).