# How Model bind to a Enum using ASp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I have a enum and I am trying to model bind it using ASP.NET MVC.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public enum ESampleTime
    {
        Value1= 0,
        Value2,
        Value3,
        Value4,
        Value5,
        Value6
    }
}
```

And I am trying to model bind it using ,

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SampleTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class="control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SampleTime,new List<SelectListItem>())
            </div>
```

This results in empty list as I am passing a new `SelectedItem` `List.`

But how do I display Value1, value2... in listBoix?

Comment: Are you want to pass enum into `ListBoxFor`? Seems you may look at these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862025/passing-enum-values-to-a-listboxfor-in-asp-net-mvc3 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143126/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-with-listboxfor-dropdownlistfor-helpers.

Comment: Is this a bad idea ? I just want to constrain user selection and not really need a listbox to bind. But as I am at design phase want to go with best practice.

Comment: You just need to add a List of "SelectListItem" to you model. Pre-populate the list in your controller and bind to the list in the drop down.