# Iterating enum getting name and value

Tags: c#, enums

I have this simple enum;

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    FOO = 1,
    BOO = 2,
}
```

I could use `GetValues` or `GetNames` but that excludes the other :-/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Iterating through an enum? (Indexing a System.Array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482729/c-sharp-iterating-through-an-enum-indexing-a-system-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly

```
var dict = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
           .Cast<int>()
           .ToDictionary(x => Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), x), x => x);
```

Comment: For enumerating values you can use `Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>()`. Also in order for this to work you need to `import System.Linq`