# Buttons in Vuforia Unity App did not work for AR game in Vuzix M400

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, vuzix

I tried to make an AR game using Vuforia on Unity and did the design for the game UI with different scenes. I tested the application using Unity Play Mode using my PC's webcam and everything worked well. When I tried to deploy the game to Vuzix M400 Smart glasses everything worked (the AR camera, image detection and other things). However, the buttons to change to different scenes cannot be pressed.

I tried to deploy the app to another Android device (android phone) but the buttons also still did not work. (Even worse, the camera did not work too)

How to make the buttons pressable on the AR app made in Unity using vuforia when deployed to AR glasses? Or is it actually a problem with the device I am using? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that Unity's `OnButton()` events don't recognize Vuzix's [nav buttons and touchpad](https://intercom.help/vuzix/en/articles/5909662-interaction-methods) input.
Since everything works with running Vuforia Engine and image detection, I believe what you are looking for is mapping [Android key codes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) to Unity's key codes. There's a thread about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69705657/how-to-map-an-android-keycode-to-a-unity-keycode)

I also wouldn't expect the app build for Vuzix to run on an Android phone. That would likely require changing the Target Architecture and project settings in Unity.

hope it helps,